# Is there a way to identify how may signals delivered, pending to given process id?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

Given a process id,  I would like to find how may signals { including real time signals } are delivered, and handled. Is there any way to get from /proc file system?, If so, how to do that ?. Kindly guide.

Comment: It's not quiet clear to me if your questions referrs to "pending" or "delivered" signals or both.

Answer (score 1):

Referring "pending signals":

One can use `sigpending()` to get a set of types of signals pending for a given process. This isn't the actual number of signals that had been sent to the process.

Referring "delivered signals":

One can set up a signal handler using `sigaction()` which in turn can count how often it is called. Anyhow the kernel or the run-time library (I'm not sure which) might decided to only call the handlers once for one or more signals of the same type having been sent close together in time.

An alternative way to collect signals is the use of `sigwaitinfo()`, probably in a dedicated thread.

Comment: The kernel does no book keeping. All signals sent to userland applications are immediately discarded.

Comment: Sure, discarded after they had been sent to userland. And may be "merged" with anyother in case both not having been sent to userland yet. Anyhow I'm not deep enough into the *linux* kernel to know whether it takes this option.

Comment: @Neox: Thanks for your comment, I edited my answer therefore.